# How do you retrieve nested arrays from csv in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

Reading a CSV via Ruby's native csv library, each row is stored as an array, but the values within it are stored as strings. However, some of my values are themselves arrays and I want to retain these.

Example row:

```
0,Yes,Local,-150,"[""Peach"", ""Almond""]",Classic,"[""Red"", ""Blue"", ""Green""]"
```

Currently I do:

```
csv = CSV.read('data.csv', 'r', :headers => true, :converters => :numeric)
```

For numbers I already use a converter, but does anything similar exist for arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, the array is formatted according to JSON rules. Try:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV::Converters[:json] = lambda{|s| 
  begin 
    JSON.parse(s)
  rescue JSON::ParserError
    s
  end
}

csv = CSV.read('data.csv', 'r', :headers => false, :converters => [:numeric, :json])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval, but only do this if you know the source of the csv. If it can be uploaded by anyone, you'll need to find another way.

```
 eval '"[""Peach"", ""Almond""]"'.gsub('""', '\'').gsub(/^\"|\"$/, '')
```

The first bit is a string of your array with the quotes. I replace the double double quotes with a single quote, and remove the trailing/leading quotes. Then it's a string containing a proper array format.